# Erasing in a WPF program

Tags: wpf, drawing, canvas, erase

How can I make a MS Paint clone in WPF?

I use Canvas and Shapes, but I don't know how to implement erasing.  Should I use different controls, image control for example, or other drawing technology?

Comment: Isn't erasing in MS Paint the same as painting with a white brush?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the object from the Canvas using canvas.Children.Remove() methods.